# how to find text in square brackets

Tags: python, regex

Find the content in the square bracket and print it including the square bracket

I am doing an NLP course, and it shows that I should use r"[.*]" to match anything in the square brackets.

I check the python documents, seems that the code is ok. But when I run it, problems occurred.

It does not just find the contents in the brackets, it also finds the contents between two pairs of the square brackets.

```py
pattern1 = r"\[.*\]"
re.search(pattern1, 'lll[hhh], sdhdjha[wwl_]')
```

I expect the output is `[hhh], [wwl_]`
but it is `<re.Match object; span=(3, 23), match='[hhh], sdhdjha[wwl_]'>`.

The contents between [] and [] is also printed.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `re.findall` instead:

```
re.findall(r'\[.*?\]', 'lll[hhh], sdhdjha[wwl_]')
```

This returns:

```
['[hhh]', '[wwl_]']
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python regexes, `*` is what is known as a *greedy* repetition qualifier: it tries to match *as much text* as possible. So in your example text `lll[hhh], sdhdjha[wwl_]`, instead of just matching `[hhh]`, it matches all the way from the first `[` to the last `]` - so it matches `[hhh], sdhdjha[wwl_]`.

To fix your regex, use `r'\[.*?\]'`. `*?` is a *non-greedy* repetition qualifier: it gives you the first match it finds by matching as little text as possible. All repetition qualifiers (`*`, `+`, `?`, `{m,n}`, etc.) are greedy by default, but can be made non-greedy by adding a `?` to them (`*?`, `+?`, `??`, `{m,n}?`, etc.)

Another minor issue with your code is that `re.search(...)` only returns the first match. If you want it to find both `[hhh]` and `[wwl_]` you need to use `re.findall...)`. So your code would become

```
pattern1 = r"\[.*?\]"
re.findall(pattern1, 'lll[hhh], sdhdjha[wwl_]')
```

For more details on how repetition qualifiers work, the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) are pretty good.

Comment: Ok. thank you for the explanation. Now I know how to use the '?' to avoid the greedy search.